# Images are displaying from Absolute path

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Image is not displaying if i provide the image path as `E:\STUFF\desktop\Images\1.jpg`
insted if i provide relative path of solution then it is displaying `/Images/1.jpg`
But i want to display image by proving the Absolute path like `E:\STUFF\desktop\Images\1.jpg`
Can any provide the solution
Thank you

```
<img src="E:\STUFF\desktop\Images\1.jpg" width="50" height="50"/>
```

Comment: Yes,.Currently i am accessing this from my local  machine, and this path exist in my local machine

Comment: yes i have given all the permissions required

Comment: Can any one provide solution plz.

Comment: My brain is not working today.  You know that this won't work on any remote machine - if you want your images stored in another folder (other than under web root), you should have a virtual directory pointing to that folder and link your images that way...